# Not understanding this recursive Fibonacci implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, fibonacci

This is not my code. I can't understand what line 3 is doing exactly, the logical operations.

```
cache = {}
def fiba(n):
     cache[n] = cache.get(n, 0) or (n <= 1 and 1 or fiba(n-1) + fiba(n-2))
     return cache[n]

n = 0
x = 0
while fiba(x) <= 4000000:
       if not fiba(x) % 2: n = n + fiba(x)
       x=x+1
print(n)
```

Comment: I hope whoever wrote that code gets their programming license revoked.

Comment: `x and y` is the same as `x if x else y`. Does that explain it?

Comment: `x if x else y` means x evaluates to true if x or/and y  evaluate to true?

Comment: @CosminChiriac no, `x if x else y` would be something like `if x: return x; else return y` (if it were a function)

Comment: I am copying this code to my "don't ever do this" list...

Comment: @zvone everything is clear now. thanks a lot

Comment: @zvone so it was a waste of time trying to comprehend

Comment: @bfontaine No, it isn't. `x and y or z` can evaluate to `z` if `x` is false *or* if `x` and `y` are both false.

Comment: Your code was being taken from https://www.w3resource.com/euler-project/euler-problem2.php

Comment: Whoever answers this question must be in doom!

Comment: @Aran-Fey It looks horrible at first, but it's not that bad when you think about it. It's in linear time and n·log(n) space like the optimal implementation, and has a cache for future calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me to be an attempt at improving the efficiency of the recursive algorithm by caching previous calculations. In the simplest recursive Fibonacci, you would simply have

```
def fiba(n):
    return (n<=1 and 1) or fiba(n-1) + fiba(n-1)
```

Which is a shorthand for

```
if(n<=1)
    return 1
else 
    return fiba(n-1)+fiba(n-2)
```

Which would return 1 for n=0, 1 for n=1, and then the next fibonacci number (calculated as the sum of the previous 2) for all n after that.

If we examine this code carefully, we see that calculating `fiba(4)` calls `fiba(3)` and `fiba(2)`, which in turn call `fiba(2)`, `fiba(1)`, `fiba(1)`, and `fiba(0)` respectively. Notice that we call `fiba(2)` multiple times, and since that itself is a recursive function, this could get expensive, especially for larger numbers, since the number of function calls increases exponentially at each level. The idea is therefore to do the work of calculating each `fiba(n)` only once, and then storing it in memory (the `cache`) so that the next time we need it, we can simply look it up instead of recalculating it.

The line you're asking about is what does most of this work. We store the `n`th fibonacci number at index `[n]` of the cache. The conditional is evaluated from left to right: first `cache.get(n,0)` sees if we've already calculated the number, and if so returns it. The 0 in the argument means that if the key `n` is not present, the cache returns `0` instead of `None`. This isn't really necessary, as either a 0 or a `None` will cause the other side of the `or` condition to be evaluated.

In short, `cache.get(n,0)` checks if the value has been calculated, and if not, we go to the other half of the `or`. This calculates the `n`th number as we did in our function without caching, either by the base case of `fiba(0)=fiba(1)=1` or by summing the previous two values.

Comment: Now, the OP can sleep well without doing intensive research to his assignment.

Answer (score 0):

**Line 3**
It looks like the first part of the conditional statement is returning zero if n is zero. The second part is either returning one or the next fibonacci number in the sequence. And all of this is being stored in a cache (really just an array).

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much this:

```
result = cache.get(n, 0)
if not result:  # i.e. if result == 0:
    if n <= 1:
        result = 1
    else:
        result = fiba(n - 1) + fiba(n - 2)
cache[n] = result
```

See the [docs on boolean operators](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) to better understand what they do.